# Inbound connections fail to connect after initiating OpenVPN connection

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, interface

There is a cronjob on another box which is reaching out to me every minute;

```
$ nc -lvnp 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
[snipped for brevity]
```

I want to eventually relay the traffic over a VPN, so I've connected to it:

```
$ openvpn admin.conf &
$ nc -lvnp 80
[no traffic or output]
```

however then I stop getting the HTTP traffic at all and thus cannot relay it. I've attached the routing tables below for reference:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.100.11.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.100.11.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
10.100.11.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.11.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Comment: Lots of information is missing. Are the boxes on the same subnet? What are the routing rules on the client? Can the client see the other side of the tunnel (in-tunnel addresses, ping)?